# Trying to sort vector of structs gets error: passing 'const user_info_t' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

I'm newbie in C++. I have a method in which I'm trying to sort vector of struct user_info_t.

```cpp
std::vector<user_info_t> phone_book_t::search_users_by_number(const std::string &number_prefix, size_t count) const {
    user_info_t one = {{"+78", "a"}, 1.0};
    user_info_t two = {{"+77", "a"}, 1.0};
    user_info_t three = {{"+79", "a"}, 1.0};
    /*contacts_info.push_back(two);
    contacts_info.push_back(three);*/
    sort(this->contacts_info.begin(), this->contacts_info.end(), numberComparator);
    return std::vector<user_info_t>(contacts_info.begin(), contacts_info.begin() + 10);
}
```

And phone_book_t class code is

```
class phone_book_t {
public:
    phone_book_t() = default;
    phone_book_t(const phone_book_t &other) = default;
    phone_book_t &operator=(const phone_book_t &other) = default;
    ~phone_book_t() = default;

    std::vector<user_info_t> search_users_by_number(const std::string &number_prefix, size_t count) const;
    std::vector<user_info_t> search_users_by_name(const std::string &name_prefix, size_t count) const;
private:
    std::vector<user_t> contacts;
    std::vector<call_t> calls;
    std::vector<user_info_t> contacts_info;
};
```

The thing is I can't sort vector because it throws an error **"error: passing 'const user_info_t' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]"**
I googled this error and I don't get it at all. I understand there's something in const keyword and for example these lines

```cpp
  /*contacts_info.push_back(two);
    contacts_info.push_back(three);*/
```

also don't compile. CLion tells me in that case that **"No matching member function for call to 'push_back' candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const std::vector<user_info_t>', but method is not marked const"**
I can't modify any public fields in phone_book_t class or anything in structs, so I would appreciate if you could help me.

Comment: For one, phone_book_t::search_users_by_number is a const memeber function.  But you modify the member variable contacts_info in it.

Comment: Thanks, copied it in variable and it works.